# Why MongoDB queries does COLLSCAN instead of INDEXSCAN?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

There are the indexes created on a collection named "taches"

```
> db.taches.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.taches"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "idProjet" : -1
        },
        "name" : "idProjet_-1",
        "ns" : "test.taches"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "id" : -1
        },
        "name" : "id_-1",
        "ns" : "test.taches"
    }
]
>
```

Theses two exemples show that theses queries are not using the indexes, and they examinate all the collections documents, don't understand why ? :

```
2023-03-26T15:36:41.691+0000 I  COMMAND  [conn11] command XXXX.taches command: find { find: "taches", filter: { idProjet: { $in: [ 73293, 71255, 71256, 75455, 75454, 75456, 75847, 75846, 75853, 75850, 75851, 75852, 75872, 75871, 75873, 75874, 75880, 75878, 75879, 75881, 76157, 76156, 76158, 76188, 76186, 76189, 76190, 76191, 76477, 76474, 76478, 77021, 77020, 77022, 77023, 77362, 77359, 77360, 77361, 77421, 77419, 77420, 78055, 78052, 78053, 78054, 78090, 78089, 78091, 78794, 78791, 78792, 78793, 79059, 79058, 79063, 79064 ] } }, projection: { id: 1, idProjet: 1, nom: 1, status: 1, ordre: 1 }, $db: "XXXX" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:7041921742719850182 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:564790 numYields:4412 nreturned:101 queryHash:D536B4A0 planCacheKey:D536B4A0 reslen:10061 locks:{ ReplicationStateTransition: { acquireCount: { w: 4413 } }, Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4413 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4413 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4413 } }, Mutex: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } storage:{} protocol:op_query 385ms
```

```
2023-03-26T15:47:56.482+0000 I  COMMAND  [conn11] command XXXX.taches command: find { find: "taches", filter: { id: 939185 }, $db: "XXXX" } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:593553 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:4637 nreturned:1 queryHash:6DAB46EC planCacheKey:6DAB46EC reslen:1207 locks:{ ReplicationStateTransition: { acquireCount: { w: 4638 } }, Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4638 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4638 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4638 } }, Mutex: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } storage:{} protocol:op_query 393ms
```

Thanks a lot

I tried many indexes rules

Comment: you use aggregate cmd or find cmd ?

Comment: It's a find command

Comment: Can you share you collection with some data with indexes ,

Comment: I also approach at upwork

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c51d06e67d8b06eb0676293"),
    "id" : NumberInt(1),
    "idProjet" : NumberInt(1),
    "nom" : "Profile Front",
    "status" : "done",
    "heuresEstim" : NumberInt(0),
    "contacts" : [
        NumberInt(3)
    ],
    "notes" : [

    ],
    "dateDebut" : "",
    "dateFin" : "",
    "groupes" : [

    ]
}

Comment: db.tester.find({id: { $in: [ 73293, 71255, 71256, 75455, 75454, 75456, 75847, 75846, 75853, 75850, 75851, 75852, 75872, 75871, 75873, 75874, 75880, 75878, 75879, 75881, 76157, 76156, 76158, 76188, 76186, 76189, 76190, 76191, 76477, 76474, 76478, 77021, 77020, 77022, 77023, 77362, 77359, 77360, 77361, 77421, 77419, 77420, 78055, 78052, 78053, 78054, 78090, 78089, 78091, 78794, 78791, 78792, 78793, 79059, 79058, 79063, 79064 ]
}
}).explain() , i have used this cmd, you can check index

Comment: Things is with this queries, the CPU increase at 500% (we have 32 vcpu available)

Comment: Is the `XXXX` database name from the log files the same as `test`from your `.getIndexes()` output? Said another way, make sure the indexes are in the correct namespace

Comment: Oh i change it to not show the right database name. It seems that the query is more complexe than the index so Mongo Prefer using COLLSCAN insteaf of INDEXSCAN

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some mistake in your sample code, recreating your scenario; it works as expected (IXSCAN):

```
db.testCollection.drop();
var arr = [...Array(5000).keys()];
var searchIds = [];

var insertManyArray = [];
arr.forEach(item => {
  insertManyArray.push({ id: item + 7000, name: item.toString() })
  if(item % 3 == 0)
    searchIds.push(item)
});

db.testCollection.insertMany(insertManyArray);
db.testCollection.createIndex({id: -1})
db.testCollection.find({id: { $in: searchIds }}).explain()
```

Explain plan

```
"winningPlan": {
  "stage": "FETCH",
  "inputStage": {
    "stage": "IXSCAN",
    "keyPattern": {
      "id": -1
    },
    "indexName": "id_-1",
```